# How do I use JSArray<T> objects from JsonUtils.safeEval() properly?

Tags: javascript, json, gwt

I'm reading a static JSON file using RequestBuilderand have confirmed that I am seeing the expected JSON in the reponse's .getText() method. I've stripped down what I'm doing to try and figure out the exact problem. This is about as barebones as I can make things.

I use JsonUtils.safeEval() to parse the response into my overlay type and pass the result into a function that will spit out the results onto the page. Obviously there's more to this method but I've left that out for the sake of brevity.

```
@Override
public void onResponseReceived(Request request, Response response) {    
    JsArray<JSONLeadTime> tmp = JsonUtils.<JsArray<JSONLeadTime>>safeEval(response.getText());
    if (200 == response.getStatusCode()) {
        renderLeadTimes(tmp);
    } else {
        AlertWindow.displayAlert(ERRORS.GENERIC_CLIENT_ERROR);      
    }
}
```

Here is the overlay type definition, for reference. For the record there's an "equipment" overlay type defined as well. You can glean the definition from the JSON below or I can include that if need be.

```
public class JSONLeadTime extends JavaScriptObject {
    protected JSONLeadTime() {}
    public final native String getFacility() /*-{ return this.facility; }-*/;
    public final native List<equipment> getEquipment() /*-{ return this.equipment; }-*/;
}
```

And an example of the JSON that's being parsed:

```
[{
    "JSONLeadTime": {
        "facility": "Temperance",
        "equipment": [{
            "name": "Coil Line",
            "value": "coil-line",
            "lead-time": 2,
            "sales-router-id": [76]
        }]
    }
}]
```

When I try to iterate through the JSArray, everything is fine until I try to access the overlay type's methods. Here's the method that's spitting out the results. When I call leadTimes.get(i), I can see that "leadTime" is a JavaScriptObject, which is what I'd be expecting at that point. When I call "leadTime.getFacility()" is where I get the NPE.

```
protected void renderLeadTimes(JsArray<JSONLeadTime> leadTimes) {
    SafeHtmlBuilder sb = new SafeHtmlBuilder();
    for (int i=0; i < leadTimes.length(); i++) {
        JSONLeadTime leadTime = leadTimes.get(i);
        sb.appendEscaped(leadTime.getFacility()); //This is where I get the NPE
        if ( leadTime.getEquipment() != null ) {
            for ( int  x=0; x < leadTime.getEquipment().size(); x++ ) {
                equipment e = leadTime.getEquipment().get(x);
                sb.appendEscaped(" - " + e.getName());
            }
        }
    }       
    view.getDivLeadTimes().setInnerSafeHtml(sb.toSafeHtml());
}
```

I'm totally at a loss. I have no idea why this isn't working. Everything I've read says this should work. Any ideas of things to try would be appreciated.

Comment: In case this is relevant, I'm locked into using GWT v2.5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your JSON array contains objects with a single `JSONLeadTime` property whose value will match your overlay type. You're missing that intermediary object between the JsArray and the overlay type.

Comment: I suspected it was something wrong with my JSON format. The file I'm using validates and the online parsers appear to parse it into what I'm expecting. I can't figure out where my issue is though. Does this look like it would parse the same using the JsonUtils? https://jsonformatter.org/json-parser/ca836c

Comment: Okay, so I just re-read your answer and want to make sure I'm comprehending. Are you saying I need an arbitrary object outside of the list of JSONLeadTime objects for the parse to work correctly?

Comment: No, I'm saying that in pure JS you'd do `leadTimes.forEach(leadTime => console.log(leadTime.JSONLeadTime.facility))`, not `leadTimes.forEach(leadTime => console.log(leadTime.facility))` (spot the `JSONLeadTime` intermediate property; you'd need another overlay with that property)

Comment: If I'm understanding correctly, what I think is my list of JSONLeadTimes is actually an object that contains my list of JSONLeadTimes as a property?

Comment: No, it's a list (`[`) of objects (`{`) that each contains your JSONLeadTimes in a `JSONLeadTime` property (`"JSONLeadTime": {`).

Answer (score 0):

In my code, I created a type first, like this:

```
/**
 * This class may not be directly instantiated, and can only be returned from a
 * native method. For example,
 *
 * <code>
 * native JsArray<JavaScriptObject> getNativeArray() /*-{
 *   return [
 *     { x: 0, y: 1},
 *     { x: 2, y: 3},
 *     { x: 4, y: 5},
 *   ];
 * }-* /;
 * </code>
 */
public class TeamMembersJso extends JsArray<TeamMemberJso> {

  protected TeamMembersJso() {
  }
}
```

And then I evaluate the raw JSON data into the JavaScript overlay instance.

```
TeamMembersJso jsoData = JsonUtils.safeEval(rawData);
```

Not sure if it's related to the direct use of `JsArray<JSONLeadTime>` in your code. It's definitely worth trying the approach I used, because it's working well for me.

I'm using GWT 2.8.2, but I don't think there are any big differences.

Comment: Sadly, this did not work for me. I appreciate it nonetheless. :)

Comment: Then, I guess you have a different problem which is not related to JsArray.